# Faker generate a phone number

Tags: java, faker

I use the Faker library to generate a phone number. How to configure the generation so that the number is output in the format +7916xxxxxxxx

```
Faker faker = new Faker(new Locale("ru", "Moscow"));
String phone = faker.phoneNumber().cellPhone();
```

I put the location on the desired segment, but the wrong format comes to the place of the phone number according to the type 999.000.999

Comment: Did you try searching the Faker documentation?

Comment: yes, and I don't understand what the mistake is

Comment: Show all relevant code you wrote...

Comment: add all for my code

Answer (score 0):

Calling [phoneNumber()](http://dius.github.io/java-faker/apidocs/index.html) gives the correct Russian format.

```java
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
Faker faker = new Faker(locale);
System.out.println(faker.phoneNumber().phoneNumber());
// +7(979)761-86-72
```

The *cell_phone* format has not been added in the [Russia's locale file](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/blob/master/src/main/resources/ru.yml#L54), only *phone_number*.

So, we can use the above method to generate Russia phone numbers.

Note: Looks like [Moscow has different format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Russia#Calls_within_a_city_or_region) for Phone Number. I guess, there is no city-wise formatting in Faker.